# Importing Java classes in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, import

I have two classes (CoinFlip and Incr) in different files and I'm trying to import Incr to use in CoinFlip:

```
package com.iRprojects.Book.Java;

import java.util.*; 
import com.iRprojects.Book.Java.*;

public class CoinFlip { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int g = 5;

        System.out.println(incr(g));

    }
}
```

and

```
package com.iRprojects.Book.Java;

public class Incr {
    public static int incr(int i){
        i++;
        return i;
    }
}
```

With the classes like this eclipse says incr() isn't found.

If I change it to:

```
package com.iRprojects.Book.Java;

import java.util.*; 
//import com.iRprojects.Book.Java.*;

public class CoinFlip { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int g = 5;

        System.out.println(com.iRprojects.Book.Java.Incr.incr(g));

    }
}
```

It compiles fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have to write:

```
import static com.iRprojects.Book.Java.Incr.*;
```

This means import of all static members from com.iRprojects.Book.Java.Incr class taking into account the access modifiers.

Comment: Just to clarify, that will import not only the static methods but also the static fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect...you are trying to access incr as if it was a local method to class CoinFlip.

In fact, it is defined in the Incr class, and there fore should be accessed like:

```
System.out.println(new Incr().incr(g));
```

Also, please consider using proper sun recommendations for you package declarations.

Comment: Yeah I made that package name before I knew to do all lowercase. So even though its static method I still have to create an object when importing another class?

Comment: No you don't.  See answer given by @unholysampler et al.

Answer (score 0):

`incr()` is a static method of `Incr`. When you don't explicitly state the class name, java will only look within the containing class. Since `CoinFlip` does not implement `incr()`, you get the error.

You also do not need the fully qualified path of the class name, `Incr.incr()` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a static import or write Incr.incr()